# React/Spring/MySQL Containerisation: Frontend Unable To Start After Pulling Image

Tags: reactjs, spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Still grasping with Docker and its concepts. I have a React front end, which I am trying to deploy to a backend REST API in Spring Boot and MySQL. Now, I'm able to build and push the images separately, i.e. one for the React application, and the other for the Spring Boot aplication.

This is my `Dockerfile` for the front-end React application.

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I'm able to run the front end on `localhost:3001` with this docker command:

`docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 3001:3000 -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true dockeruser/app-client`

And this is for my Spring Boot backend:

```
FROM openjdk:15-jdk-alpine

COPY app-server-web/target/app-server-web.jar /app-server-web.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app-server-web.jar"]
```

Now I am able to build both of these and push them to dockerhub. I want to compose them now, but for some reason the front end is not able to start on the port that I assigned it to. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  application-db:
    restart: always
    container_name: application-db
    image: 'mysql:5.7.30'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: application_database
      MYSQL_USER: alee
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: anotherpassword
    ports:
      - '3308:3306'
    volumes:
      - './initial.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initial.sql'
      - null
  application-server:
    restart: on-failure
    image: 'dockeruser/app-server:latest'
    expose:
      - '8080'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: >-
        jdbc:mysql://application-db:3306/application_database?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: alee
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: anotherpassword
    depends-on:
      - application-db
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
  application-client:
    restart: on-failure
    image: 'dockeruser/app-client:latest'
    expose:
      - '3001'
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    depends-on:
      - application-server
    networks:
      - frontend
networks:
  backend: null
  frontend: null
```

These are the logs I get upon `docker-compose up`

```
application-client_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.128.3/
application-client_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
application-client_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
application-client_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
application-client_1  | Starting the development server...
application-client_1  |
```

I'm pretty sure something is wrong in `docker-compose.yml` but I'm not sure what it is?

Comment: `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: >- ` <<

Comment: Hi @abestrad, I took that out and it seems to be the same...

Comment: Should they have to be in different networks? How are they supposed to communicate? Is it even valid to set both networks to null? Have you check the docs?

Comment: Could you please try to expose port 3000 for application-client in docker-compose file (if nothing change then please remove expose instruction at all)

Comment: Does the `application-client` container just exit, with status code 0?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze yup that's in the logs too, sorry I missed it earlier

Comment: Set it to have `stdin_open: true`.  This is a bug in the react-scripts library.